# Changing Button's Text Dynamically

Tags: java, android

I had already setup the buttons and the layout properly, but I'm having an issue to dynamically change the text in the buttons

|B|P|M|F|

When the letter b is clicked: change b to e, f, g and each change of letter stops for 1 second
When the letter p is clicked: change p to q, r, s and each change of letter stops for 2 second
and so on.

I searched Google, and many results show that I need some sort of threading to accomplish it. Can anyone point me to the right direction?

Thanks

Sorry if I wasn't clear enough. My exact problem is to change the text when the user has touched on a button 4 times that pauses each changed text for 1 to 2 seconds not exactly. This is part of the source code

```
public class someClass extends Activity implements OnClickListener
{
    //Single Vowels
    Button a_button;
    MediaPlayer mp = new MediaPlayer();
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);  

        MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener completionListener = new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener()
        {
            public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mediaP) 
            {
                mediaP.stop();
                mediaP.release();
            }
        };

        mp.setOnCompletionListener(completionListener);

        a_button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.a_button);
        a_button.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    public void onClick(View v) 
    {
        switch(v.getId())
        {
              case R.id.a_button:
              mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.a_multiple);
              mp.start();   
              break;
        }
    }
}
```

So what I want to do is when the user pressed the button, there would be some sort of speech, for example, this is an apple, and the text will change accordingly with the speech. The speech is pre-recorded, and all I have to do is to trial and error and match the speech with the changing words. In total I have about 10+ buttons that does the same thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What exacly is your problem? Change the text? Make one or two seconds pause?

Have you got some source code?

To create a "Make ... in ... seconds" you can make:

```
Handler handler = new Handler();

// Then call (in a Thread):

handler.postDelayed(new Runnable()
{
    public void run()
    {
        label1.setText("b");
    }
}, 1000);
```

Comment: Sorry I didn't make my question clear, I updated my question.

Comment: To be honest, I'm not really good in threading (ugh!). I suppose I have to create a class and extending AsyncTask, and for the method doItInBackground I should somehow call handler.postDelayed, then call (new changeText()).execute()) to change the text of the button, what if I had 10+ buttons?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you need to use threading. Here is good tutorial on [how to use threads in Android](http://www.vogella.de/articles/AndroidPerformance/article.html). You may use it as starting point.

Comment: Thank you for your tutorial, I will have a look at it